# google chrome specific background overflow issue with html5 audio player

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, overflow

I have created an audio player using the soundmanager2 library and customized the css with a new look and some transitions to fit my websites design. However, the problem I am having is the fact that I am having a problem with Chrome not containing the background color within the limits of the border radius, resulting in a overflow problem. This issue is non existent in firefox or internet explorer.

Any avice will be strongly appreciated. Im trying desperately since days to fix this.

Here is the page to my audio players so you have an idea of what is going on with the background.

http://tinyurl.com/agvmueo

PS: if more information is needed let me know and I will provide them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after 20 minutes of debugging, the answer was clear, this is what you have to do:

Add this in line 42 in 360player.css in the `.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis` class: `background-color: white;`

Remove `background-color:white` from `.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis .sm2-360ui` at line 43.

Hope this fixes the problem.

Comment: The method works, I tried this myself once but it generates a different and even more annoying issue. I uploaded the change for you to see. Now the issue is that in firefox the title slides down and remains hidden when the player is in play / pause state but in Chrome the text stays behind the round progress bar. Crazy thing. This is truly crazy. Man im literally turning insane :D

Comment: Give your `.sm2_link` a `z-index:99` although this will make the text above the round stuff ;0

Comment: Thats really the issue that Im trying to keep the text hidden after hover or play / pause state not show it. If I give it a z-index of -99 then all the players text is unvisible. Im thinking of targeting sm2_link through one of those selectors but truly have no idea how since I tried a few combinations already. Now when I reverse everything and give it the white background which we removed then the problem is fixed but then the overflow problem happens again :/